# A normal subgroup of $ GL(n, K) $

Tags: group-theory, linear-groups

Let $ F $ be a field and $ K $ be an extension of $ F $. Define the set, $$ E(n, K, F) := \{ M \in GL(n, K) , \det M \in F \} $$

Show that $ E(n, K, F) $ is a normal subgroup of $ G(n, K) $ and also determine the quotient $ G(n, K) / E(n, K, F) $.

My idea : Showing the normality is easy. Also, I can prove that $$ G(n, K) / E(n, K, F) \simeq K^{ \times }/ F^{ \times } $$
by using the determinant map $ \psi : GL(n, K) \rightarrow K^{ \times} , \psi(M) = \det M, M \in GL(n, K) $, noticing that $ \psi $ maps $ E(n, K, F) $ onto $ F^{ \times } $ and using the isomorphism theorem for normal subgroups.

However, I still do not get much insight about the structure. Is there any place else where $ E(n, K, F) $ appears?

Comment: It is not completely clear what they mean by "determine the quotient ..." and it is possible that the isomorphism with $K^\times/F^\times$ is exactly what they want for an answer. I am not sure what more you could say in general. If $K$ is finite with $|F|=q$, $|F|=q^n$ then $K^\times$ is cyclic and $K^\times/F^\times$ is cyclic of order $(q^n-1)/(q-1)$.

Comment: Yes, I was also unclear about the same phrase. I think I will move on, accepting $ K^{\times} / F^{\times} $ as an answer. Thanks for the response!